# Twister Core compilation Error

Tags: c++, python-2.7, bitcoin, twisted.web, mersenne-twister

I am trying to compile twister-core on windows 8.1 (64 bit) using Cygwin.
I am following the steps which are given in the [link Compile Twister for Windows](https://github.com/miguelfreitas/twister-core/wiki/Compiling-for-Windows)
I have copy the code from here :[Github "Twister-Core"](https://github.com/miguelfreitas/twister-core)
I have run the “./bootstrap.sh” successfully without any error.
When I am  running the “make” command it show the error and make process failed:

> **Error**: /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/config.hpp:577:5: error: #error
>   You must add -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options.
>   # error You must add -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options. /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:192:1: error: pasting “stack_st_” and “(”
>   does not give a valid preprocessing token DECLARE_STACK_OF(X509_NAME)
>   ^ /usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h:103:1: error: pasting “stack_st_” and
>   “(” does not give a valid preprocessing token
>   DECLARE_STACK_OF(PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO)
>   /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:753:30: error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘unsigned’ unsigned long chtype); ^
>   /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h:753:50: error: expression list treated
>   as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive] unsigned long
>   chtype); ^ Makefile:1407: recipe for target
>   ‘libtorrent/src/web_connection_base.o’ failed make: ***
>   [libtorrent/src/web_connection_base.o] Error 1

Comment: `#error You must add -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS` seems explicative...

Comment: You must add -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply , please tell me how set the compiler option for add it : -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS

Comment: I Have added compiler this -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS option in make file and this error has been resolved . But Other errors are also remaining.Please help me to compile twister, Thanks in advance.

Errors Errors given bellow: $ make /usr/include/openssl/x509.h:192:1: error: pasting "stack_st_" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token DECLARE_STACK_OF(X509_NAME) ^

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-DOPENSSL_SYS_WIN32` to the compiler options did the trick for me with OpenSSL version 1.0.2r.